# How to get only "Chapter 1. The title of the chapter" in the left of header

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I am trying to use fancyhdr, but I can't get it to not show the section and to keep the normal case for title and 'Chapter'.

How can I have my heading to be "Chapter 1. The title of the chapter" (left aligned on all pages)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % optional
\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
```

Comment: Thanks! I removed the \thepage as I already have the page number in the bottom. I now found out that removing the section is just a matter of overwriting it with this commands.

Answer (score 6):

The [titlesec](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package offers a very good alternative to the `fancyhdr` package for designing page styles; here's a little example doing what you need:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}% to generate filler text

\newpagestyle{mystyle}{%
  \headrule\sethead{\chaptername\ \thechapter. \chaptertitle}{}{}
  \setfoot{}{\thepage}{}}
\pagestyle{mystyle}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}
\section{Test section}
\lipsum[1-40]

\end{document}
```

delete `\headrule` if you don't need the rule below the headline.